# Why does initializing a string in an if statement seem different than in a switch statement?

Tags: java, string, if-statement, switch-statement

I'm learning Java and I'm making simple programs to find the season that a month is in, based off some book examples. These two classes demonstrate two ways of testing a value: if/else if statement, and switch statement. The thing I'm confused with is the string that is used to hold the season. When I declare it as just `String season;` it works with the if statements. But with the switch statement, doing that produces a "The local variable season may not have been initialized" error.

```
public class IfElse {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int month = 5;
        String season;
            // isn't initialized, works fine

        if(month == 12 || month == 1 || month == 2)
            season = "Winter";
        else if(month == 3 || month == 4 || month == 5)
            season = "Spring";
        else if(month == 6 || month == 7 || month == 8)
            season = "Summer";
        else
            season = "Fall";

        // this is okay
        System.out.println("May is a " + season + " month.");
    }
}
```

Not initializing season at the same time as declaration works fine for the above code, but the season variable in the last `println()` for the switch produces an error if it's declared the same way.

The following code doesn't work:

```
public class Switch {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int month = 5;
        String season;
            // HAS to be initialized, currently causes error
        switch(month) {
        case(12):
        case(1):
        case(2): 
            season = "Winter";
            break;
        case(3):
        case(4):
        case(5): 
            season = "Spring";
            break;
        case(6):
        case(7):
        case(8): 
            season = "Summer";
            break;
        case(9):
        case(10):
        case(11): 
            season = "Fall";
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid month");
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("May is a " + season + " month");
    }             // produces an error if season isn't initialized to null or ""
}
```

What causes this? Is it the braces enclosing the switch statement, or a problem with the switch statement itself? How is initializing a string inside an if statement any different than initializing it inside a switch statement? I just can't seem to understand this.

Sorry if this is extremely obvious or if it seems like a dumb question.

Comment: In the code that doesn't work, which season is month 13?

Comment: [Meta discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378528/1394393) about this question.

Comment: FYI there's no need for brackets around the case values. `case 12:` etc is fine.

Comment: BTW it is a good idea to use uninitialized variables like this as it makes it clear if you have considered all path (however as you if example shows you might not have considered it correctly). (Opposed to using `String season = ““;` which is often seen in code from less experienced programmers) and i think upcoming case expressions will make this a better experience.

Comment: Just to be explicit (since none of the answers is): this is *unrelated* to `if` *vs* `switch`. Your two pieces of code are simply not equivalent, but you *can* write equivalent code (that exhibits either behaviour) with both `if` and `switch`.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

That is because you did not specify what season has to be in the default case. What happens when month is not within 1-12? `season` will not be initialized.

If you are expecting strictly only 1-12 as month input, then you might want to consider throwing an `Exception` in `default:`

```
default:
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid month");
```

Comment: And to point out a small bug in the question askers if/else implementation, the else will set any invalid month to `Fall`. If month was set to 42, it would print `Fall`.

Comment: @DrZoo You're completely right. I did that out of laziness because I knew I would never set the month value out of range, but that also meant that there would never be a situation where season is uninitialized. Changing the else to an else if also gave me the same error as in the switch statement. So I now realize my problem was with when the variable is (or isn't) being given a value.

Comment: @jkofskie I do not want to be as mean as this now sounds, but the problem was that you ASSUMED the value will never be above 12. Never assume anything in programming, when you start assuming things (especially user input) you get yourself in problems (and in this case the compiler was nice enough to warn you).

Comment: @KamiKaze some assumption is useful, though.  If you really know that the input value is guaranteed to be in the acceptable range, it shouldn't be necessary to add a guard clause.  Defending against conditions that you know will not arise can lead to unreadably complex code.  The point here is that the programmer should be careful to separate what the programmer knows about the program from what the compiler knows, or should be expected to know.

Answer (score 9):

In your first example, there is no path through the code that fails to assign a value to 'season'.  In the second example, the default case does not assign a value, so the last print ("May is...") can be executed with an uninitialized value.

Comment: Yeah, for some reason I subconsciously assumed that would only be an issue if the value for month was actually out of the defined range, but I forgot Java doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 6):

In your `if`/`else` code, there is an assurance that the variable `season` will get a value. That is, the `else` statement.

Your `switch` code does not have it. Look what will happen to the variable `season` if the given value for month is `13` -- it will not get a value, and will remain un-initialised.

Answer (score 4):

You should use this

```
public class Switch {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int month = 5;
    String season;
        // HAS to be initialized, currently causes error
    switch(month) {
    case 12:
    case 1:
    case 2: 
        season = "Winter";
        break;
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5: 
        season = "Spring";
        break;
    case 6 :
    case 7 :
    case 8 : 
        season = "Summer";
        break;
    case 9 :
    case 10 :
    case 11 : 
        season = "Fall";
        break;

    default:
        season = "Invalid";
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("May is a " + season + " month");
}             // produces an error if season isn't initialized to null or ""
}
```